# Why there are the two frames, when inspect on webview element of a chrome packaged app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webview

Picture first: [Two frames in the chrome developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30mac.png).

I have a chrome packaged app, which have a webview element. The src of the webview is set to about:blank as shown. But why there are two frames from the chrome developer tools when inspect on the webview element.

This is very confusing, because when I add some script using `addContentScripts`, the `window` object in the injected script seems to be the same as the second frame (chrome-extension://...), but the `window` object in the webview page's own script is the top frame.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer myself. Link first:[Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

In brief, due to security considerations, chrome keeps each content script, as well as the page itself, in different script environments called the isolated world. So all scripts share the same DOM, but the their js environments are different.